# Merge and copy 2 audio tracks from video file

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a video file with 2 audio tracks. I wish to utilize a single `ffmpeg` operation to have a video with:

1. Merged audio
2. Audio #1
3. Audio #2

With this I can merge the audios, ending up with video with a single merged audio track:

```
ffmpeg -i "myvideo-with-2-audio-tracks.mkv" -c:v copy -c:a aac -ac 2 -filter_complex amerge=inputs=2 "myvideo-with-1-merged-audio-track.mkv"
```

I can use a second command to combine everything, but this requires processing twice. If I add `-c:a copy` to the end, I get an error:

```
Streamcopy requested for output stream fed from a complex filtergraph.
Filtering and streamcopy cannot be used together
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may use channel mapping and codec indexing:

`ffmpeg -i "myvideo-with-2-audio-tracks.mkv" -c:v copy -filter_complex "amerge=inputs=2[a]" -map 0:v -map "[a]" -map 0:a:0 -map 0:a:1 -c:a:0 aac -ac:0:2 2 -c:a:1 copy -c:a:2 copy "myvideo-with-1-merged-audio-track.mkv"`

---

- `"amerge=inputs=2[a]"` - gives the merged audio a temporary name `[a]`.
- `-map 0:v -map "[a]" -map 0:a:0 -map 0:a:1` - maps the video, then the merged audio then the first input audio stream then the second input audio stream (map to output streams).
- `-c:a:0 aac -ac:0:2 2 -c:a:1 copy -c:a:2 copy` - Applies `aac` codec for the merged audio, and `copy` codec for the two input audio streams.

---

As commented by the OP, we have to set `-ac:a:0 2` instead of just `-ac:0 2` for getting track #1 with 2 audio channels.
Add `-disposition:a:0 default` for defining the first audio track as default.

Comment: +1 Thanks very much. I also needed to just change `-ac:0 2` to `-ac:a:0 2`. Otherwise I was getting audio track #1 with 4 channels (instead of 2) and twice the bitrate. The track also didn't play right in my video player (altho audio player confusingly had no issues).

Comment: Also, the 1st audio track doesn't get the `"default track"` flag set, so my video player plays the 2nd audio track by default. This could seemingly be fixed with `-disposition:a:0 default`.

Comment: You are right, my answer was focused on getting "Merged audio" and "Audio #1" and "Audio #2". I didn't try to play it. I updated my answer.